# Joint Distribution of Record Values

Tags: probability

I am writing a short report on record values, and I am trying to understand the following proof for the joint distribution of record values.

I have attached a picture of the proof and I have marked where I am getting stuck. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri6gX.png)

For a bit of background on record values:

Let $X_1$, $X_2$,… be a sequence of random variables with probability density $f(x)$. Define:

\begin{equation} L_0 = 0,   L_1 = 1, L_{n+1} = min(j: {X_j} >  {X_{L_n}}) \end{equation}
\begin{equation} X_n = X_{L_n} \end{equation}

The random variables $X_n$ and $L_n$ are called upper record values and upper record times.

The proof by resnick doesn't really make sense to me. For example, this might be a bit silly to ask, but I am not even sure why there is a $dx$ term and where the summation comes from. Hence any guidance will help me tremendously.

Thank you.

Comment: could you tell me what is the reference for the image attached? also consider writing up the content of the image using mathjax, [such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992)

Comment: this might be a bit late, but, regarding your question, the author seems to be conditioning on $\{L_1=j_1<\dots<L_n=j_n\}$, summing over all values of $1<j_1<\dots<j_n<\infty$ and then using law of total probability for continuous random variables (this is where the terms $dx$ come from).