# On record values of i.i.d exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, maxima-minima

Let $(\xi_n)_n$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables such that $\xi_0\sim exp(1)$. Let $T_0=0$ and
$$
T_n:=\inf\{j> T_{n-1}; \xi_j>\xi_{T_{n-1}}\}.
$$

I'm interested in understanding the process of records $Y_n=\xi_{T_n}$. In particular, the distribution of $X_n:=\xi_{T_n}-\xi_{T_{n-1}}$. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548367/joint-distribution-of-record-values) question the OP links an image with the following lemma

> **Lemma 1.1.** There exists a sequence $(\xi'_n)_n$ of i.i.d r.v's with $\xi'_0\sim exp(1)$ such that the sequence of records $Y_n$ can be written as
> $$
> Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i'
> $$

and the OP says that it is a proof by Resnick, however the OP doesn't tell what is the exact reference and they are not responsive in the comments. Could someone give me the reference to this book/paper?

In the chapter 4 of the book *Extreme Values, Regular Variation, and Point Process*, Resnick seems only to study the case of hitting times
$$
R_n:=\inf\{j> R_{n-1}; \xi_j\in B\},
$$
where $B$ is a fixed event.

I would also be very interested in any other reference related to the process $Y_n$.

---

EDIT:
In response to Misha Lavrov.

I first thought that memoryless would give me that $X_n\sim exp(1)$,

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(X_k\leq t)&=\mathbb{P}(\xi_2-\xi_1\leq t|\xi_2>\xi_1)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathbb{P}(\xi_2\leq t+s, \xi_2>s)}{\mathbb{P}(\xi_2>s)} e^{-s}ds\\&
    =\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s}(1-e^{-t})}{e^{-s}}e^{-s}ds=1-e^{-t}.
\end{align*}

But i am not sure if the first equality holds. My intuition is that the larger $Y_n$ gets, the harder is to beat it, and when it happens, $Y_n$ is beaten by a smaller margin each time.

Comment: Doesn't memorylessness immediately tell us that $(\xi_j - \xi_{T_{n-1}} \mid \xi_j > \xi_{T_{n-1}}) \sim \text{Exp}(1)$?

Comment: I first thought yes, but i am not sure. I've edited my question regarding this

Comment: I guess I appreciate that the formal proof is tricky. But regarding the intuition: it is true that the larger $Y_n$ gets, the harder it is to surpass it; but the point of memorylessness is that once you *do* surpass any threshold, the amount by which you exceed it should not depend on how large the threshold is.